# Can't set TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators to True in TypeScript 1.8.5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, angular

I downloaded a project from codeproject that demonstrates a simple working angular 2 application. I unblocked it, loaded it into Visual Studio 2013, and was able to successfully execute it as it.

I then cleaned the application and rebuilt it, and the application no compiles. It outputs the error: "Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning."

Under Visual Studio 2013, you currently need to edit the csproj file and add the entry

```
<TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
```

to get it to work. But under TypeScript 1.8.5 this doesn't appear to do anything.

Here's the app:
[First Angular2 App with TypeScript and Visual Studio 2013](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1060262/First-Angular-App-with-TypeScript-and-Visual-Studi)

I know that I can go into the TypeScript build tab and untick the box "Do not emit outputs if any errors are reported" and it will generate the code and run successfully, but this should be prevented for real errors, not this one.

Any ideas how I might get this to work in VS2013? (I should point out, I did the same thing in VS2015 and got the same failed outcode.)

Comment: Are you certain you are actually running Typescript 1.8.5?  Visual Studio tends to get very "sticky" with global environment variables for the TS version.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of VS2013: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

Comment: Yes it is using Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5.

Comment: In the csproj file the TypeScriptToolsVersion it is set to TypeScript 1.8. When I open a command prompt and execute tsc --version, it says 1.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by setting the [experimentalDecorators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler option to true in tsconfig.json.

Here I have modified an [example tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file to include this option.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "files": [
        "core.ts",
        "sys.ts",
        "types.ts",
        "scanner.ts",
        "parser.ts",
        "utilities.ts",
        "binder.ts",
        "checker.ts",
        "emitter.ts",
        "program.ts",
        "commandLineParser.ts",
        "tsc.ts",
        "diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts"
    ]
}
```